# How to change the color of the number if the value decrease or increase?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I would like to change the number color red if the value is less than -15 or need to change the color green if the value is + 15

Ad also please let me know if we can change the color inbetween , that is >15 and <20

Can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: All are well. what you have tried?

Comment: Similarly, I recommend you at least add pseudo code.

Comment: no its a psd design . My jquary code is not working. Can you help me?

Comment: Show us your "jquary" code.

Comment: If it is on page load, it very easy. On page load add/remove css class based on range.

Comment: is this table created with varying number of rows and columns or if its a static please post the table html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a class depending on the score

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MB7c3/)

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th> 
        <th id="positive">Positive</th>
        <th>Negative</th>
        <th>Avg. Rating</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td id="positiveScore">13</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>4.5</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.red {
    color: red;
}

.green {
    color: green;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#positive").addClass((parseInt($("#positiveScore").text()) >= 15) ? 'green' : (parseInt($("#positiveScore").text()) <= -15) ? 'red' : 'blue');
```

Comment: And if values are changing, do not forget to add .live after  the selector.

Comment: @user3718333 `.live` is deprecated. and there is no event here, so I don't see how

Comment: This code will only work for a single element. Can you make it work on all numbers (and also remove those ugly repetitions, please)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I need the colour change for the number not heading .  If the number is less than 15 , that number want to red . Thanks

Comment: Which number? Be specific